# Get rows based on elements present inside the Postgres int array

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is my postgres 9.3 table

```
      id    arr
      1     [1,2,3]
      2     [1,2]
      3     [1]
      4     [2]
      5     [4,5,6]
```

If i search for 1,2 i am expecting output as below. I want all the rows which either contains 1 or 2.

```
  id    arr
  1     [1,2,3]
  2     [1,2]
  3     [1]
  4     [2]
```

I tried using below query i.e. using ANY

```
  Select * from test where arr = ANY ('{1,2}'::int[])
```

It gives an error

```
 ERROR: operator does not exist: integer[] = integer Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 30
```

How do I achieve this?

SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/63c4f/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the overlap operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html):

```
Select * from test where arr && '{1,2}'::int[]
```

Comment: You are the savior :)